# Its possible to use VSCode SFTP extension with WSL/Ubuntu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, sftp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I need to use Windows in the company to development. I enabled WSL2 and installed Ubuntu 20.04. The developer environment is hosted in an AWS EC2 instance. To made changes to the developer environment I use [Natizyskunk's SFTP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp) for VSCode.

However, the extension is not working when VSCode is launched from a WSL environment.  It fails to sync, with no error message.  I think this is because WSL2 is behaving like a remote task in VSCode. Can someone help me?  I hate using Windows for development, and I would like to use WSL2 with SFTP extension instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what you are asking. It's probably language barrier - what is *habilited*? *ambient*?

Comment: @Felix I think after staring at it enough (and thinking about synonyms that might get translated poorly), *habilitied* might be *enabled* and *ambient* almost certainly means *environment* in this context.  Bbarbosa7 - I'm going to make some edits to your question to hopefully improve it.  If I don't get it right, please edit to see if you can help make things more understandable.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, after editing, we're still going to be left with questions - Please edit your question to specify *what* doesn't work with the SFTP extension with WSL.  Do you get an error?  If so, please copy/paste that error into your question (not as an image, as text).  Also, it might be useful to link to the SFTP extension that you are using.

Comment: And "environment" might not be quite right either.  But regardless, you are running EC2 instances which seem to have SSH enabled (for SFTP, at least).  Have you considered using the "Remote - SSH" extension (from Microsoft, included in the "Remote Development" extension pack?  You shouldn't even need WSL - VSCode should be able to connect directly to the EC2 instance.  Again, I'm taking some guesses as the original question wasn't very clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for editing @NotTheDr01ds! Sorry for my poor English.
I'm already connected to EC2. In VSCode I'm using Natizyskunk's SFTP extension. But when I open VSCode from Ubuntu (WSL2) the extension doesn't sync. No error message appears. It's like she just doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @Bbarbosa7 - I wish I had a suggestion for you, but I'm at least happy to help with the communication as I can.  I've edited your additional info into the question, which will bump it, at least.  Perhaps with that additional detail, someone will have an idea.

Comment: Apparently things are working now. I reinstalled Ubuntu and reconfigured the extension and everything is working. Thanks anyway to everyone for the help!